# BST Find Height Recursivly

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, height, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to find the height of a Binary Search Tree in my program, and keep coming upon this recursive solution to find the height:

```
int maxHeight(BinaryTree *p) {
  if (!p) return 0;
  int left_height = maxHeight(p->left);
  int right_height = maxHeight(p->right);
  return (left_height > right_height) ? left_height + 1 : right_height + 1;
}
```

Can someone explain to me how this works? I don't understand how it adds up the height.  It looks like it should just go through each side of the tree and return 0.

Comment: Create a small tree on paper, then walk through it as though you were the program. Make sure that the height of the root's right and left subtrees are different. Doing that will probably tell you more than anything we explain here.

Comment: Also keep in mind that in recursion, each recursive call is completely separate, with its own local variables, and its own return value.  Each call to `maxHeight` returns the height for its piece.   The fact that it calls out to itself to measure its left and right children is the magic of recursion.  One of the key concepts to recursion is the idea of a "recursion stack."  You might want to draw out what that looks like at each step also if you get lost.

Comment: Maybe that formulation of the body is clearer: `return p? std::max(maxHeight(p->left), maxHeight(p->right)) + 1: 0;`: if there is a node compute the result as maximum of the height of the left and the height of the right subtree and add 1 for the node. Otherwise there is no node, i.e., the height is zero.

Comment: @JoeZ I quite like this expression "**magic** of recursion". I was quite confused about how this code `return 1 + max(maxDepth(root->left), maxDepth(root->right));` works, it's really magical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm works this way:
If the tree I am looking at does not exist, then the length of the tree is 0.

Otherwise, the length of the tree is the maximum height of the two sub-trees I have plus 1 (the plus 1 is needed to include the node you are currently looking at).

E.g. if I have a tree with no branches (i.e a stump) then I have a height of one, because I have two subtrees of height 0 and the max of these heights plus 1 is 1.

another example:
If I have a tree:

```
A - B - C - D
    |   |
    E   F
```

(where a is root)

then, height is not 0, as A is not null

height = max(height(left), height(right)) + 1.

height of left at A is 0, because A has no left branch.

height of right branch is the height of B + 1.

to work out the height of B, we consider B as a completely new tree:

```
B - C - D
|   |
E   F
```

now
height = max(height(left), height(right)) + 1.

to work out the heigtht of left, we conside E as a completely new tree:

```
E
```

this exists so it's height is not 0

however, it's two branches do not exist, so it's height is 1 (each branch has height of 0)

back to the parent tree again:

```
B - C - D
|   |
E   F
```

we were working out height, and found out the height of the left branch is 1.

so height = max(1, height(right) ) + 1

so, what is the height of right?

once again, we consider the right branch as it's own tree:

```
C - D
|
F
```

the problem is the same as before
height = max(height(left), height(right)) + 1

to work out height(left), we consider F by itself

F

F has height of 1, because it has two null branches (i.e. max of two 0 heights's plus 1)

now looking at right

D

D has height of 1 for same reason

back to parent of F and D:

```
C - D
|
F
```

height of C is:

max(height(F), height(D)) + 1

= max(1, 1) + 1

= 1 + 1

= 2.

So now we know height of C, we can go back to the parent:

```
B - C - D
|   |
E   F
```

recall, we worked out the length of B's left branch as 1, and then started working out it's right branch height.

We now know that the right branch has a height of 2

Max(1, 2) is 2.

2 + 1 = 3

Therefore, height of B is 3.

Now we know this, we are finally back to our original tree:

```
A - B - C - D
    |   |
    E   F
```

we already worked out the left branches height at 0, and then started working on the right branch.

we now know the right branch has a height of 3.

Therefore,
    height(a) = Max(height(null), Max(height(B))
              = Max( 0         ,    3          ) + 1
              = 3+1
              =4

done. The height of A is 4.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go through that step by step, I would not have been able to figure that out on my own

Comment: OMG, finally I find the very helpful answer. Thank you very much! Really help a lot. This recursion is like going through one level by one level.

Answer (score 0):

The function only returns 0 if the binary tree is null. That makes sense because if the tree is null, there are no nodes to count so the height is 0.

If it's not null, then the function will add 1 (the height of the current node) to the height of the left or the right child sub-tree, whichever is greater.

How does it know the height of the child sub-trees? By calling itself recursively passing in the left child or the right child so that the next recursion starts one level down in the tree.

What happens when you call the function for the first time passing in the root of the tree? The function first calls itself recursively travelling down the left-most children until it finds the leaf node. It calls itself one more time passing in the left child of the leaf node, which is null. This last call doesn't recurse any more and just returns 0. The function then recurses to the right child of the leaf which also returns 0. It then adds 1 for its own  height and returns.

We are now at the parent of the left-most leaf and as before it will recurse to the right child (sibling to the leaf). That one might not exist (returns 0), be a leaf (returns 1) or have children (returns >1). Whatever the return value, it will be compared to the left-most leaf (height 1) and whichever is greater will be incremented (always adding the height of the current node) and returned as the height of the sub-tree rooted at the current node.

Notice that the recursion will keep "unrolling" as it travels back up to the root but at each level, it will first recurse further down the right child sub-tree. This is what's known as a depth first search. Eventually, the whole tree will be visited and the outstanding maximum height computed all the way back to the root.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not memory friendly. For example, when you run this method, the `height_left` and `height_right` vars will still be saved in the memory. So, what if you run this function billions of times? I suggest to return with no variables, for instance

```
return max(maxHeight(p->left), maxHeight(p->right));
```